# How to Paginate More Than 1 Array? PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have Three Arrays.. I want to make this 3 Arrays to have 5 result per page, each of it..

**Array 1**

```php
$Array1 = Array
(
    [0] => 86456
    [1] => 86456
    [2] => 86456
    [3] => 86456
    [4] => 86456
    [5] => 86456
    [6] => 86456
    [7] => 86456
    [8] => 83981
    [9] => 83981
)
```

**Array 2**

```php
$Array2 = Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 2
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 3
    [8] => 3
    [9] => 3
)
```

**Array 3**

```php
$Array3 = Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 3
    [7] => 1
    [8] => 2
    [9] => 3
)
```

I want at the end of the day to be used in table like this

```html
TMDB ID Season Numbers  Episodes Numbers
14842      1                1       
14842      1                2       
14842      1                3       
14842      1                4       
14842      1                5       
84476      1                1       
84476      1                2       
84476      1                3       
84476      1                4       
84476      1                5
```

Let Say **Result per page is 5**.. **How can I paginate this three arrays together.. so when you click next.. they all should go next page**

Comment: This data feels like it came from a database? why is it in three seperate arrays?

Comment: Yes that one it come from Database.. But I have another one that is not from Database.. That why I ask a question that way.. So I can know how to work with the other one that is not from database

Comment: so the first step would be to create a foreach loop that builds a multi dimentional arrays into the data structure you want, you can use a numeric key to grab the data from your multiple arrays eg `$array[$key]` and use that within each item. then you can use [array_slice()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to create your pagination by selecting a portion of your array based off a `pageNumber * itemsPerPage` calculation, eg page 2 with 20 per page will mean start at offset 40 for a length 20 items.

Comment: Stack Overflow already has pages that demonstrate the individual techniques that you require for this task.  Please do not dump your jobs/requirements on Stack Overflow without attempting to self-solve and narrow your problem.  This is also not a clear [mcve] because you say you want 20 rows per page, but you only gave 10 rows per array.  Despite receiving an answer that resolved your problem, this question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To merge the three arrays and be able to paginate them simultaneously, first you must make sure that the three arrays have the same number of elements and are in the same order.

You can achieve this by combining the three arrays into a multidimensional array using the `array_map()` function, as shown below:

```
<?php

$Array1 = array(86456, 86456, 86456, 86456, 86456, 86456, 86456, 86456, 83981, 83981);
$Array2 = array(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3);
$Array3 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3);

//merge arrays
$combined = array_map(null, $Array1, $Array2, $Array3);
```

The result will be a multidimensional array with the following structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 86456
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 86456
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 86456
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 86456
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 4
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 86456
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 86456
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 86456
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 86456
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 1
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 83981
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 2
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 83981
            [1] => 3
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

Once you have this array, you can paginate it using any of the array pagination techniques in PHP. For example, if you want to display 5 elements per page, you can use the `array_slice()` function to get a subarray of 5 elements at a time:

```
$num_per_page = 20;
$current_page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

$offset = ($current_page - 1) * $num_per_page;
$paged_data = array_slice($combined, $offset, $num_per_page);

foreach ($paged_data as $row) {
    //print row
}
```